# Reversing Games like Manfred dis

Tags: assembly, game-hacking, binary-editing, api-hacking

I've looked at as many resources on Manfred and Manfred's work

I've watched the DEFCON 25 Live talk about what he hacked.

[Here](https://youtu.be/ZAUf_ygqsDo)

I've also looked, listened and read the dark net diaries Part One -

[YouTube](https://youtu.be/3dkRG3WlAR8)

[Dark net diaries part one](https://darknetdiaries.com/episode/7/)

Part Two -

[YouTube](https://youtu.be/s2tce_kQ_QE)

[Dark net diaries part two](https://darknetdiaries.com/episode/8/)

From what my understanding is to bypass the HWID bans he ran the game and did a full memory dump, he also captured the packets sent off the game and started reverse engineering the game and started reversing the routines within a game. I've tried for a few month now to figure out how he managed to do things like this but their is no clear method on how Todo so. I figured the best place to ask would be here.

**Questions**

```
- How did Manfred do it?
 - What can I do to get started in this field of game hacking?
 - What was the method Manfred had used?
 - Is their any resources on this?
Any help is appreciated. TL;DR - How did Manfred hack so many online games
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manfred has 20+ years of experience and many skills, so don't expect to get there overnight. As a starting point:

1. Read Beej's guides: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
2. Write a client and server, use a standard protocol like HTTP.
3. Practice intercepting/modifying traffic between your client and server. Try  OWASP ZAP, BurpSuite or similar.
4. Write a dll
5. Read up on dll injection
6. Inject your dll into your client program
7. Use your dll to intercept/modify client/server traffic
8. Modify your server to have a fake inventory/stats/store system.
9. Attempt to use integer overflows to modify the results of inventory/stats/store actions.
10. Add encryption to your client/server communication
11. Does your dll still intercept/modify traffic? If not, fix it

This should give you plenty of learning without having to jump straight into the deep end with a real game. I find that attempting something without the prerequisite knowledge can result in you being sidetracked reading/learning and/or giving up.